# Postgresql regexp_replace() backslash and double quotes

Tags: postgresql, regexp-replace

I am trying to import JSON file where a value contains data like this

> "\"Koslov Git †girish\" Ges"

The return should be like `"Koslov Git †girish Ges"`

The extra `\"` are the troubles

I tried `REGEXP_REPLACE(values, '\\''+', '''', 'g')` with no luck. How can I get rid of this. Note the first and last double quotes should not be replaced

Comment: Why are you replacing backslash escaped single quotes (and any following single quotes)?

Comment: The return should be like ```"Koslov Git †girish Ges"```

Comment: So why replacing single quotes if you want to remove double quotes?

Comment: Where am I replacing single quotes. If I knew what I am doing wrong probably I wouldn't ask the question

Comment: In your regexp. There are only single quotes.

Comment: @stickbit....thanks for advising....seems like someone helped me in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with data(json_object) as (
    values ('"\"Koslov Git †girish\" Ges"'::jsonb)
)

select regexp_replace(json_object::text, '\\"', '', 'g')
from data;
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d6e6d93482bf3eae65b7e14c3958ad52)

Comment: I have tried this also. but there is no single quotes around the object. Its a json object.